# What's the source IPs of AWS SNS HTTP/HTTPS notification?

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, notifications, firewall, amazon-sns

I have configured AWS SNS notification to call my HTTP endpoint. I need to open my firewall to allow AWS SNS to call it.

However, I cannot find any information about SNS HTTP(s) notification call IPs. I have caught a few IPs **(54.240.194.1,54.240.194.65,54.240.194.129 )** by it's calls. But I'm not sure **what's the full list of SNS HTTP notification source IPs.**

I can open my firewall as 54.240.194.0/24. But no official information this is correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of IP addresses from which Amazon SNS notifications are sourced is [provided in the Amazon SNS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=2347). We update this post as the IP information changes.

Please note that while notifications will usually be sourced from an IP in the same region where your topic was created, this is not guaranteed e.g., a notification sent from a topic created in US-EAST-1 may be sourced from either US-WEST-1 or EU-WEST-1. In other words, you should add all addresses on this list to your ingress rules, even if you only plan to use a single region.

Answer (score 4):

In this situation SQS is probably more appropriate because you will be initiating the connection to Amazon instead of asking AWS to reach out to you. This means no changes to your firewall are required and you are not poking holes in your security...

If you need SNS notifications for other end points, you can pump SNS to SQS for this specific end point:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html

Comment: Looks like the question has been edited, and at least in its current incarnation, this answer is wrong.
The question is about SNS doing HTTP POST as a notification, not about SQS at all.

Comment: The point I was making here is that poking unnecessary holes in your firewall is typically bad. These two services interop very well. In this case SQS would initiate an outbound request for subscribers and you don't have to swiss cheese your firewall. You can still use SNS for other end points, but SQS would be a better choice IMOP. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html

Comment: Definitely, that's what I use SQS for especially for private services.
Unless you already have a public endpoint for the server, that is.

Comment: but in this case the OP has to open the firewall, thus the suggestion that SQS is the better choice here

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure you can't count on any particular IP address or range.

If you want to secure your endpoint, or at least ensure that any messages sent to it actually originate from AWS, this document may help:

> ...you can verify the authenticity of a notification,
>   subscription confirmation, or unsubscribe confirmation message sent by
>   Amazon SNS. Using information contained in the Amazon SNS message,
>   your endpoint can recreate the string to sign and the signature so
>   that you can verify the contents of the message by matching the
>   signature you recreated from the message contents with the signature
>   that Amazon SNS sent with the message.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.verify.signature.html

Comment: The list of source IPs is provided in [the Amazon SNS forums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329129/whats-the-source-ips-of-aws-sns-http-https-notification/23333272#23333272).

Comment: But they are unfortunately not guaranteed to not change - with or without notice. I wasn't saying you could not find out the IP's, just saying that you can't necessarily count on them to remain the same, i.e. build a solution around a hard-coded list of IP address.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer above is out of date/expired in the Amazon forum.

This link may be more help and, hopefully, permanent, but is for ALL IP ranges, evidently.

From
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html....

[AWS IP address ranges](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json)

Here's the tool to use to filter/search that massive file
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html#filter-json-file